# Custom Post Type UI with ACF

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a custom post type ui with custom field.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Diseases & Conditions
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="section inner-cont">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="main-title">
              <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      
          <?php $mydiseases = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'diseases_condition' 
          )); ?>
          
          <?php while( $mydiseases -> have_post() ) : $mydiseases -> the_post(); ?>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                
                <div class="card-text">
                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                </div>
                <div class="card-btn">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn btn-primary">read more</a>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>

          <?php endwhile; ?>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But my page is not showing custom post-type details, as like thumbnail, excerpt, Title etc...

Here is Screenshot
[image]

I want to add those into a new page. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? `have_post()` is not a function, it's `have_posts()`.

Comment: Thank you. It is solve. But I cannot show excerpt or cannot fetch value from custom field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you linked the acf-fields to the post-types? then just call `echo get_field('your_field_name_here') ;` from inside the loop. or  `echo get_field('your_field_name_here', 'id_or_something') ;` from outside the loop.